# Querying wikidata via SPARQL by resource identifier obtained from another query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to query wikidata with SERVICE keyword by giving it wikidata resource id fetched from my ontology into a variable. I store the wikidata id as string in my ontology. Normally, you need to tell wikidata endpoint which item you want by using prefixes(e.g. wd:Q1048). Here I need to do this by using a variable. Wikidate doesn't have a property for storing entity ids. So I need to give the Id as the subject in the query. Below in ?wid the stored variable is "wd:Q1048". It is a string so it isn't recognized as an element of wikidata. Is there any way that I can query wikidata this way?

```
PREFIX lit: <http://purl.org/net/cnyt-literature#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT distinct ?writer ?play ?character  ?wid ?child WHERE {
    {
        ?writer lit:writerOf ?play .
        ?play lit:character ?character .
        ?character lit:wikidataUri  ?uri . BIND (IRI(CONCAT("wd:",?uri)) as ?wid)
    }
    SERVICE <http://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
        ?wid p:P40 ?child
    } 
}
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: The problem is that you put the prefix into quotes - that means it is a string with the characters `wd:` and nothing else. `BIND (IRI(CONCAT(wd:,?uri)) as ?wid)`

Comment: I tried it, when I ommitted the service part and see what your suggestion results in, wid returns empty. When I put the SERVICE part back, it returns irrelevant entities from wikidata. wid value results in different value from uri such as wd:Q5050 whereas uri is Q1048.

Comment: Ok, you have to wrap the `str` function around the prefix -> `BIND (IRI(CONCAT(str(wd:),?uri)) as ?wid)` Note, providing some sample data makes testing for us easier - I don't want to generate data by myself to why queries of other people are not working. Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve next time

Comment: Great, thanks. I will be providing sample data next time.

Comment: Ok. And feel free to provide the answer here and *Accept* it by yourself. This will help others searching for similar topics as answered ones will be ranked higher.